# Where to find corresponding drivers?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card

I've re-installed  win xp sp3 and now have a lot of problems finding the corresponding drivers.

There are many yellow quest marks in device manager. There is no sound, graphic driver is missing, the machine cannot even go to internet.

Here are data from CPU-Z

```
cpu - amd athlon+  

Motherboard - hp0A64h

chipset - ATI Xpress 200 (RS480)

Graphic interface - PCI express
Graphics - AsusTek Computer Inc. ATI Radeon

Here are yellow quest hardware IDs from Device Manager

Other devices  
Audio Device on High Definition AUdio Bus
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1002&DEV_AA01&SUBSYS_00AA0100&REV_1002
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1002&DEV_AA01&SUBSYS_00AA0100

Audio Device on High Definition AUdio Bus
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0260&SUBSYS_103C280A&REV_1004
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0260&SUBSYS_103C280A

Ethernet Controller
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_167B&SUBSYS_280A103C&REV_02
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_167B&SUBSYS_280A103C
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_167B&CC_020000
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_167B&CC_0200

SM Bus Controller
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4385&SUBSYS_280A103C&REV_13
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4385&SUBSYS_280A103C
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4385&CC_0C0500
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4385&CC_0C05

Video Controller (VGA Compatible)
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68F9&SUBSYS_30001043&REV_00
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68F9&SUBSYS_30001043
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68F9&CC_030000
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68F9&CC_0300
```

Any help, pls.

Comment: Right-click the first device with the question mark icon you see in the list, and choose **Properties** from the context menu. Select the **Details** tab and then post here the hardware ID. Repeat the same steps for the other devices.

Comment: @and31415, I did as you said.

Comment: Go to the manufacturer's website and get the latest drivers, then install them.  What's the problem?

Comment: @techie007, how can I know who is manufacturer?

Answer (score 0):

use [Unknown Devices Identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html) to determine what's the brand and the model name of each hardware. Then go to its manufacturer webpage and download the driver.